# Why are these dimensions equal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

For a finite $K$-algebra $A$ and $L\supset K$ fields, why do we have$$\dim_K A=\dim_L(A\otimes_KL)?$$ I ran across this a couple of times and it's always assumed to be quite obvious, which it isn't to me.
(I have very little experience when it comes to working with tensor products.)

Comment: Given a basis $\{a_1,\dots,a_d\}$ for $A$ over $K$, can you prove that $\{a_1\otimes1,\dots,a_d\otimes1\}$ is a basis for $A\otimes_KL$ over $L$?

Comment: @GregMartin Sadly I don't. The first thing that pops in to my head is looking at things like $l(a_i\otimes_K1)$, but we only know that we have linearity for elements of $K$ and not for arbitrary $l$'s in $L$...

Comment: @GregMartin I actually don't quite get in what way we can consider $A\otimes_KL$ to be a vector space over $L$, since it is generated as a $K$-vector space

Comment: I can identify with your instinct that the obstacle to this problem isn't really the problem itself, but understanding tensor products! Being a $L$-vector space essentially means that there's a well-defined multiplication by $L$. You're right that there's no reason to expect such a multiplication on $A$ itself; but if $\sum x_j \otimes y_j$ is a (representative of a) generic element of $A\otimes_K L$, then multiplying by $\lambda\in L$ yields simply $\sum x_j \otimes (\lambda y_j)$. (Indeed one can view this as the main purpose of taking tensor products.)

Comment: @gebruiker To follow up on Greg Martin's comment, $ - \otimes_K L$ is an extension by scalars functor from right $K$-modules to right $L$-modules, in case you want to read more about the general construct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, if $V$ is any vector space over $K$, then $\dim_K(V) = \dim_L(V \otimes_K L)$. In fact, $V \cong \bigoplus_B K$, where $B$ is some basis of $V$, so that $V \otimes_K L \cong \bigoplus_B L$ (using that tensor products commute with direct sums and that $K \otimes_K L = L$).